# Parsing Xml file with namespace and sorting values in descending order

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, ilist

I am trying to parse the following xml file : http://reports.ieso.ca/public/DispUnconsHOEP/PUB_DispUnconsHOEP_20110714.xml

My goal is to get the maximum `price` with its associated `hour` and the minimum `price` with its associated `hour`.

The logic that I am applying is as follows:

Parse the Xml file and pass it to a IList which contains pairs of `hour` and `price`

Sort the IList in Descending order based on the `price`

Retrieve the first value in the IList as the maximum value whereas the last value in the IList as the minimum value.

My Code is:

```
XNamespace nsPriceHr = "http://www.theIMO.com/schema";
        XDocument xDocument =
            XDocument.Load("http://reports.ieso.ca/public/DispUnconsHOEP/PUB_DispUnconsHOEP_20110714.xml");
        XElement xEl1 = xDocument.Element(nsPriceHr + "IMODocument");
        XElement xEl2 = xEl1.Element(nsPriceHr + "IMODocBody");
        XElement xEl3 = xEl2.Element(nsPriceHr + "HOEPs");

        var data = (from x in xEl3.Descendants(nsPriceHr + "HOEP")
                    orderby x.Element(nsPriceHr + "Price").Value descending 
                    select new HourPrice
                    {
                        Hour = x.Element(nsPriceHr + "Hour").Value,
                        Price = x.Element(nsPriceHr + "Price").Value
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

My Problem is: the List is not getting sorted as expected. The HourPrice object which takes the two values of `Hour` and `Price` has both data members as string.

I am using C#, .NET 3.5 SP1 and working on winforms. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`System.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx). In particular, you may be interested in [`ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32.aspx) and [`ToDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todecimal.aspx). These functions take a string (or one of various other data types), and convert it to an `int` or a `decimal` respectively.

```
var data = (from x in xEl3.Descendants(nsPriceHr + "HOEP")
    orderby System.Convert.ToDecimal(x.Element(nsPriceHr + "Price").Value) descending 
    select new HourPrice
    {
        Hour = System.Convert.ToInt32(x.Element(nsPriceHr + "Hour").Value),
        Price = System.Convert.ToDecimal(x.Element(nsPriceHr + "Price").Value)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Edit:

Here is one way you might check for missing values:

```
string valueString = x.Element("ElementName").Value;
int value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(valueString);
```

If your problem is that the strings aren't empty, but aren't in the right format either, you will have to convert them to the right format before you convert. I.e., you must strip the `$` from a string like `$6.47`.

Comment: I used that, but it gives me an null exception error and does not allow me to convert

Comment: @reggie: Can you post full text of the exception's message? What is giving you the null reference?

Comment: @reggie: That means that the string you are trying to convert is not a valid representation of an int/decimal. What kinds of strings are stored in `Hour` and `Price`? They must be in a numeric format. `12pm` will not work, neither will `$6.45`. Instead they must be `12` or `6.45`. Also, if the value is `null` (or an empty `string`, you will have problems. In this case, you may want to default to `0` or throw an exception, depending on whether you are ok with missing values.

Comment: check the xml link that I have provided in my question. None of the values are null and they are numbers obviously. I can't understand whys is it having problems sorting or converting.

Comment: This may sound really lame. I was converting both my values to integer instead of decimal. thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @reggie: Can you write some code that works until the format exception is thrown, then prints the value that is not being successfully converted? Then we will have something to work with.

Comment: @reggie: Ah, glad you were able to fix it :)